# Has Captain America entered the Olympics or competed in a world level competition?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

After watching this scene:

Being that I was a professional athlete once and won my fair share of World level competition medals (only a couple really) etc., that scene piqued my curiosity as to whether Captain America has entered the Olympics or competed in a competition of some sort and competed against highly trained professional athletes?

And if he did, how did he fare?

This is more of a question about Captain America in the Marvel universe.

Comment: But wouldnt' the judges say "super soldier serum = doping"?

Comment: @TeemPorary, good point. I was drug tested every month when competing, but the question is, would any drug testing agency be able to detect the super serum?

Comment: @Valorum, if that is a marvel pic, why not make it an answer? I will upvote  it.

Comment: @KyloRen - I should imagine that Captain America's blood chemistry would be instantly suspect. His indicators would be all over the place.

Comment: @Valorum, damm, and yes I would suspect that too. But, I wondered if he had in the comics.

Comment: Isn't Captain America supposed to be unswervingly fair & possessing an advanced sense of morality? If so, **he** would exclude himself from contests with athletes that lacked the serum he was given, since he would see it as cheating.

Comment: I've read many scenes in comics where a hero is having an angst-crisis and wonders why he didn't go make a fortune in sports.  And the answer they give themselves most often is that it would be some variation of dirty skunk cheating.  Some folks have less problem.  In the original days, Northstar of Alpha Flight used his power to be a superstar on the skiing circuit.

Comment: This makes me flash on Batman. Confined to a wheelchair, Batman growled in frustration at not keeping the streets safe.  A wild and whacky solution came up.  A mind-swapping gizmo was available.  A young friend and gold medal Olympian (pentathlon, I believe) volunteered to be Batman's body.  The mad science was done and Batman went back to work.  Batman's inner thoughts considered the Olympian athlete body "not bad", but not quite up to standards.  Certainly better than nothing.  (this scene always makes me roll my eyes when fans state "Batman is just a normal guy!")

Comment: That video is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any comicbook instances of him competing in the Olympics, or any other organised sporting event, but the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (Vol.1 #2)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1_2) tells us precisely what would happen if he was to do so.

> Captain America has athletic ability, strength, speed and endurance superior to any Olympic athlete who ever competed.

In short, given his remarkable constitution, he could (theoretically) compete in every event simultaneously and would win every event that he entered.

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that the sticking points would be the IOC requirements for event qualification and the scheduling on the day but pshaw! with your logic.

Comment: Basically, Hitler would really want to sign him up for the German New Man Olympics. He even looks the part. Get Leni Riefenstahl to do a body-affirmative movie, too.

Comment: Too bad his response would be to, invariably, punch Hitler in the face.

Comment: @Carson - indeed; https://youtu.be/rtSrWn7eYbU?t=97